# is there a flaw in this md5 implementation?

Tags: c, md5, md5sum, bacula

ive  been looking at an issue with bacula cloud support which requires md5 calculation
and have been trying to use https://github.com/firebladed/bacula/blob/Branch-11.0/bacula/src/lib/md5.c and am getting bad md5 errors from amazon s3

so i tried compiling the code directly into a md5sum executable see ([Makefile](https://github.com/firebladed/bacula/blob/Branch-11.0/bacula/src/lib/Makefile.in))

and im getting different md5s from that of ubuntu md5sum

```
md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Ulrich Drepper, Scott Miller and David Madore.
```

[Example File that gets wrong md5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZveB4-cc30qVOHaUt59yi0JTcrcFQsJI/view?usp=sharing)

2521308b3fe3836623f78708a5c988d6 - ubuntu md5sum

e972192662d26a25af5fb895cf79b175 - compiled md5sum

am testing with simple command line

```
./md5sum <file>
```

for compiled md5sum

```
md5sum <file>
```

for system md5sum

using the linked example

ideally if its something simple id like to fix it

Comment: certainly appears so. Raise your concerns with the author(s).

Comment: How are you testing it? It could be that you are feeding it different data (like one with newline and one without or something like that).

Comment: testing by passing file as parameter, added detail to question

Comment: md5.c does 4 bytes at a time.  How are you telling it the byte order?

Comment: @stark Shouldn't matter for a byte stream such as a file... FWIW, my tool is producing the same hash as the ubuntu one (well, not surprising)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file contains `0x00` bytes, whereas the program uses `while(fgets(buf, ...)) } { MD5Update(..., strlen(buf)) }`. `strlen` reports smaller size than the "line" length (your input file seems to be binary), so the generated md5sum is of a different set of bytes.

Convert your input data to text (`cat -v part.1`) and pass then to both programs, or fix the program with something along `for (int c; (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF; ) MD5Update(&ctx. &c, 1)`.

Comment: thx, as i need to handle binary files ill try the fgetc method and see where i get

Comment: fixed in a slightly different way, using fread do while loop, but 0x00 was defiantly the issue